# listboxes multiple choices different descriptions error

Tags: c#, winforms, listbox, user-controls

I have created a *listbox*, within it there should be multiple choices, by selecting one of the choices there will be displayed the chosen choices description in a *label*, this differentiating from choice to choice

I came up with this code:

```
       public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            listBox1.DataSource = choices;              
            listBox1.DisplayMember = "name"; 
        }

        private void listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            label1.Text = valikud.ElementAt(listBox1.SelectedIndex).description;
        }

        List<dynamic> choices = new List<dynamic>()
        {
            new {

                name = "Choice 1",
                description = "Description 1"
            },
            new {
                name = "Choice 2",
                description = "Description 2"
            }
        };
    }
}
```

This works on a regular form, the problem comes when I add this to my other program into `user control`, the problem occurs at:

```
List<*dynamic*> choices = new List<dynamic>()
```

The error states :

*Error  CS1980  Cannot define a class or member that utilizes 'dynamic' because the compiler required type 'System.Runtime.CompilerServices.DynamicAttribute' cannot be found. Are you missing a reference?*

**UPDATE**: The problem was due to my outdated .net framework version, I updated to 4.6 when before it was 3.0

But now this caused a new problem which is at:

```
 private void listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            label1.Text = *choices.ElementAt(listBox1.SelectedIndex)*.description;
        }
```

The error states:

*Error  CS0656  Missing compiler required member 'Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.CSharpArgumentInfo.Create'*

How am could I possibly fix this?
-Thanks

Comment: I think it's the problem with the framework the project is targeting.  What is the framework version of the project?

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya 3.5 I think

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to check the framework version of the project where you are getting this error.

dynamic keyword and type are supported in .NET Framework 4.0 or higher.

Make sure that the target framework of your project to 4.0 or higher and it should resolve your issue.

Comment: I updated my answer. Apologies for the previous answer.

Comment: I installed the required framework versions, but the error is still there

Comment: Does your project point to the correct version? Which versions you installed?

Comment: So I got this solved, the project wasn't targeted to the right version of .net, but this caused a new problem, I'll edit this to the post

Comment: Better you ask another question instead of modifying this

Comment: I couldn't due to the character limit

Comment: Add reference to `Microsoft.CSharp`.

Comment: I can't seem to figure this out, where should i add this reference

Comment: Add this reference to your project.